# when choose Float or Number types in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I m reading some table in Oracle and i m looking like some times they are using "FLOAT" type or "NUMBER" for practicaly the same value

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_A 
  (  sen_id NUMBER, 
     sen_Rating NUMBER,    --here i m wating something like 12,9984
     sen_mont DATE,
     sen_value FLOAT(64),    -- here im waiting too something like 0,83387
    );
```

so what should i choose Float or Number when i want to save a number with decimals ,  is there a case where is better use one or other?

Thanks in advance, Enrique

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref129) explains how FLOAT differs from NUMBER - mainly the difference between binary and decimal precision. When to use each is an application/design call, though Oracle recommends not using the ANSI FLOAT anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FLOAT is just an alias for NUMBER datatype in Oracle. So you can  choose any of them, as they are just the synonym of each other.

See the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm):

> **FLOAT [(p)]**
>
> A subtype of the NUMBER datatype having precision p. A FLOAT value is
> represented internally as NUMBER. The precision p can range from 1 to
> 126 binary digits. A FLOAT value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

Comment: hi @Rahul Tripathi !!  then why are they using both ??  and not just Number or both Float ?? i m looking that in a database of a  big company , I mean that people should know what they are doing

Comment: But [float](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00209) has binary rather than decimal precisin, so it's not quite this simple. It's representd internally by `number`, but it's not just an alias - `float(5)` is not the same as `number(5)`.